I get ERROR: REJECTED when uploading a file to ShareFile
I am trying to upload a file to ShareFile. In Postman, I am able to do it but in Python  get 200 status code and "ERROR: REJECTED" response body.
Here's my code.
def upload_file(self, file: bytes, folder_id: str, file_name: str, etag: str, content_type: str):
        url = f"{self.api_base_url}/sf/v3/Items({folder_id})/Upload2"
        headers = self._get_headers()

        # First, get URL for file upload
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json={
            "FileName": file_name,
            "Raw": True,
        })
        upload_url = response.json().get("ChunkUri")

        headers = self._get_headers()
        headers["Content-Type"] = content_type
        response = requests.post(upload_url, headers=headers, data=file)


did you check folder permissions?

@JoseCabreraZuniga thanks, I have. The problem was that FileSize property was not specified in the request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79086617/8544967

When getting the URL, FileSize also has to be specified unless it's specified elsewhere.
# First, get URL for file upload
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json={
    "FileName": file_name,
    "Raw": True,
    "FileSize": len(file),
})

